# Can you use Typekit in Flash Movie players?

Tags: flash, typekit

Maybe I'm not understanding how typekit works.  But will I be able to use typekit fonts for the closed caption text within my flash movie player?  The closed caption text is not html content....it's served by an xml file and then rendered by flash actionscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There not a way to do what you wish in Flash current web font implementations from web font services use @font-face via CSS. Typekit and other web font services like ours - WebINK - rely on a browser to make a request for a font file. We rely on matching the user agent string, domain and other information to send back the correct file format.

At this time web font services are html content only.